# OpenJDK JMH sometimes prints (*interrupt*) in results. What does this exactly mean?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I use OpenJDK JMH 0.9.3 and sometimes i get a result log file like this one below.
What means (*interrupt*) here?

```
Forking 1 times using command: [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/...]
# Run progress: 53,85% complete, ETA 00:01:26
# Fork: 1 of 1
# Warmup Iteration   1: 19950765,000 us/op
# Warmup Iteration   2: (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) (*interrupt*) 18107134,000 us/op
# Warmup Iteration   3: (*interrupt*) 14439157,500 us/op
Iteration   1: 13571806,000 us/op
Iteration   2: 7484946,500 us/op
Iteration   3: (*interrupt*) 12386565,000 us/op
Iteration   4: (*interrupt*) 7245477,500 us/op
Iteration   5: (*interrupt*) 9047236,000 us/op


Result: 9947206,200 ±(99.9%) 11103651,130 us/op [Average]
  Statistics: (min, avg, max) = (7245477,500, 9947206,200, 13571806,000), stdev = 2883582,937
  Confidence interval (99.9%): [-1156444,930, 21050857,330]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means your workload was interrupted by JMH, quite possibly because it overrun the iteration time. It prints "(*interrupt*)" to let you know the score was obtained with active intervention of JMH, and may be unreliable.

You can annotate your benchmark with `@Timeout(time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS)` annotation and it will know that it will take longer. By default when you run some batch Measurement (without time limit set), it will [default to 10 minutes time limit](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2014-September/001363.html).